# Soap request to WCF web service on Azure via Javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services, post, soap

I have a WCF web service hosted on Azure as a cloud service. I am trying to send a POST SOAP request from an HTML/JS web application it appears I cannot POST a SOAP envelope across domains. I have tried a variety of POST techniques with no avail. Has anybody experienced this before and/or is aware of a work around?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, as per AJAX cross-domain requests cannot be made unless the server says " I'm ready to accept".

Normally, when you make a cross domain request an `OPTIONS` request is made to the server, to check what all methods and options are given allowed at the server. The server responds with a set of headers which says further communication can be made or not.

So, if you want to do a cross domain `AJAX POST/GET`, you can do it provided either of the following is possible

```
 -> Server says "I am ready to accept" for your client request - which normally does not happen

 -> Use a proxy server in your layer, to forward the request to target server, and revert back the response.
```

For more info, you can scroll on `MDN` forums or `CORS` facts.